# Unable to read request.getInputStream

Tags: servlets, struts2

Following is my action class

```
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.servlet.ServletInputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

import org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext;
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletRequestAware;
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletResponseAware;

public class AccessRequest extends ActionSupport implements 
                  ServletRequestAware,ServletResponseAware {

  /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private HttpServletRequest request;
      private HttpServletResponse response;

     /**
     * @return the response
     */
    public HttpServletResponse getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    /**
     * @param response the response to set
     */
    public void setResponse(HttpServletResponse response) {
        this.response = response;
    }

    /**
     * @return the request
     */
    public HttpServletRequest getRequest() {
        return request;
    }

    /**
     * @param request the request to set
     */
    public void setRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        this.request = request;
    }

    public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request){
            this.request = request;
          }

          public HttpServletRequest getServletRequest(){
            return request;
          }

          public void setServletResponse(HttpServletResponse response){
            this.response = response;
          }

          public HttpServletResponse getServletResponse(){
            return response;
          }


  public String execute() throws Exception{
        request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
        InputStream in = null;
        ServletInputStream si = request.getInputStream();
        System.out.println(si.available());//Getting 0
        System.out.println(request.getContentLength()); //Getting 938
        return SUCCESS;
  }

}
```

I am getting si.available() = 0 where as request.getContentLength() showing 938

Why struts is not reading request.getInputstream?????

I face the same problem while using Servlet in Struts2

Any Idea? Please help

Comment: You've already asked this before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340621/request-getinputstream-is-null-or-empty Please don't repost the same issue once again. If you feel that the answers doesn't suit you or that you don't get good answers, then you should be using the `edit` link to update/improve your question.

Comment: I am facing this problem only in struts. In JSF and normal servlet project it is working fine

Comment: I am bit curious to know that "request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();" getting what values. Please check whether you are getting request NULL or not.

Comment: No i am not getting NULL value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Per my knowledge

Struts framework uses the getParameter to populate data into the form beans 
before calling the execute method, we cannot use the request.getInputStream

Please correct me If its worng